# Assign a sql script into a variable

Tags: sql

This is my first time doing this and the reason is because I would like to avoid typing the same sql script code when using the conditional "if". My first option was creating a variable and assign the "select" statement to it , now depending on another variable value , I will just change the "where" condition but instead of getting all the columns and rows that I get on a regular sql script , I'm getting just one cell with the text assigned to the variable. Below is my code:

```
DECLARE @SQLScript varchar(MAX)='' ,
        @Subordinate int = 1;

SELECT @SQLScript = N'SELECT * FROM Account
    WHERE AccountID = 345015' 
IF @Subordinate = 1 
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQLScript =@SQLScript +' AND Status=2 ORDER BY 1 asc' 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQLScript =@SQLScript +' AND Status=1 ORDER BY 2 asc'
END
SELECT @SQLScript
```

What I'm getting after executing the above script is 1 cell showing the following text "SELECT * Account where AccountID = 345015 AND Status=2 group by 1 asc" . What I need is to get the table data from that script

Comment: [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Just making sure; are yo using SQL Server?

Comment: Yes I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need yo execute your dynamic script with simply using `EXEC()`. Also you need to put FROM to your select, use `ORDER BY` instead of `GROUP BY` to order your query. Her is your corrected script :

With using `EXEC()` :

```
Declare 
@SQLScript varchar(max)=''
,@Subordinate int = 1;

Select @SQLScript = N'SELECT * FROM Account
where AccountID = 345015'

if @Subordinate = 1
begin
Select @SQLScript =@SQLScript +' AND Status=2 order by 1 asc'
end

else
begin
Select @SQLScript =@SQLScript +' AND Status=1 order by 2 asc'
end

--select @SQLScript
exec(@SQLScript)
```

With using `sp_executesql`. Be aware, you cannot use `VARCHAR` to execute your query with `sp_executesql` . You must use `NVARCHAR`(or `ntext`,`nchar`).

```
Declare 
@SQLScript NVARCHAR(max)=''
,@Subordinate int = 1;

Select @SQLScript = N'SELECT * FROM Account
where AccountID = 345015'

if @Subordinate = 1
begin
Select @SQLScript =@SQLScript +' AND Status=2 order by 1 asc'
end

else
begin
Select @SQLScript =@SQLScript +' AND Status=1 order by 2 asc'
end

--select @SQLScript
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLScript
```

Comment: +1 for correcting the script.  Although, I would recommend that they use sp_executesql instead of just exec for the reasons listed here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/17/exec-vs-sp_executesql/

Comment: and this is all assuming they're using SQL Server :)

Comment: @StuartAinsworth I will update the script for both solutions. Thanks for double checking.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

execute sp_executesql @SQLScript

to execute the query